# Can a kickstart file have multiple %pre or %post sections?

Tags: kickstart

I am new to using ks.cfg files and came across one with 2 %post sections and thought it may be a mistake. The first %post section is empty and is just

```
%post --nochroot


%end
```

The second %post does have some code in it.

I did spot a reboot at the end of the command section of the kickstart file, so wondered if perhaps it could be 2 separate %post sections for before and after the reboot? But so far found nothing in the documentation to indicate that could be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put as many `%post` (or `%pre`) sections in the kickstart as you want, they are processed in order present in the file. You can have multiple `%post` sections if you want to use different [options](https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#chapter-6-post-installation-script) (like here with `--nochroot`) or just to separate different tasks for better readability.

From [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/kickstart-script-file-format-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user):

> **Script section count and ordering**
>
> All sections except the command section are optional and can be present multiple times. When a particular type of script section is to be evaluated, all sections of that type present in the Kickstart are evaluated in order of appearance: two %post sections are evaluated one after another, in the order as they appear.